# App Engine - How to passe JSON to Queue

Tags: java, json, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I would like to use Queue for execut long tasks with App Engin.

So I create a Queue and set the url (this url is for execut the process)

"columnNamesWrapper" is a POJO, so I convert it to String (json)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitColumnMapping", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String submitMapping(@RequestBody final ColumnMappingCommand columnNamesWrapper) throws JsonProcessingException {

    Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
    TaskOptions task = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/startProcessing").param("columnNamesWrapper", mapper.writeValueAsString(columnNamesWrapper));
    task.method(TaskOptions.Method.POST);
    task.header("Content-type", "application/json");
    queue.add(task);
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/startProcessing", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String startProcessing(@RequestBody final ColumnMappingCommand columnNamesWrapper) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("RUN");

}
```

Problem,the task throw exception : 
[INFO] Infos: Web hook at http://127.0.0.1:8080/startProcessing returned status code 415.  Rescheduling...

And 415 status code is Unsupported Media Type, so the JSON.

What can I do
Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `startProcessing` method expects raw JSON data in body, while your request sends JSON encoded as a POST parameter.

Either you send JSON data in body via `task.payloady(mapper.writeValueAsString(columnNamesWrapper))`, or

or you accept JSON data as POST parameter:

```
public @ResponseBody String startProcessing(@RequestParam("columnNamesWrapper") String columnNamesWrapper) {
```